# sql query in shell script @xyz.sql

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, sqlplus

Can anyone please tell me the exact meaning/significance of `@forecast2.sql` in below query , the given query is a part of one shell script. Also how can I find the exact sql query executed by `@forecast2.sql`

Below is the code:

```
sqlplus -s / @forecast2.sql $SCHED_ID > /tmp/BR_forecast
```

I need to find the sql query that's been executed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that `sqlplus` will execute script called `forecast2.sql`. 
You could locate it:

```
> env | grep SQLPATH
-- path where scripts are located
```